# c# windows phone 8.1 get button content as a string

Tags: c#, xaml, button, windows-phone-8.1

I'm new to c# and wp development.

On "Holding" I want the Content value of the button as a string in my c# code.

```
<Grid>
    <Pivot>
        <PivotItem>
            <Grid>
                <Button x:Name="Venue1" Content="Venue1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,0,0,0"VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="342" Height="102" Grid.Row="1" Holding="Holding"/>
            </Grid>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

I thought it was pretty straightforward and did this but doesn't work.
TextToSpeech is a method that takes a string and reads it out. It reads out "Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid"... why?

```
private async void Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs) 
{
    await TextToSpeech(this.Content.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-

```
private async void Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs) 
{
    var obj = sender as Button;
    var content = obj.Content;
    await TextToSpeech(content);
}
```

What are you doing wrong is by using this. Here **this** does not belong to button but for the page itself. In place of **this** you have to use the corresponding button object that i have already shown how to use.
For further reference see [This Keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dk1507sz.aspx)

you can also use name of the button to get its content that is little bit hard coded.

Comment: thank you for quick responses everyone :) also needed to ToString() the content at the end but worked in no time. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty straightforward :)

```
await TextToSpeech(this.Venue1.Content.ToString());
```

Comment: this works too but i prefer mr.loop's version so i can use this same method for my other buttons. thanks anyway!

Comment: @koko sure - both methods work, so whichever you prefer is fine. :)